# Why does RegOpenKeyExA fail to open a key path with a space in the name?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Why does `RegOpenKeyExA` throw a path not found error according to the error codes from Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

other paths (no spaces) do open flawlessly

```
int res;
HKEY hKey;
res = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender",
                     0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_WRITE|KEY_READ|KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
std::cout << " Error code ["+res+"]"<<std::endl;
```

the error code I am getting is `2`

I am running the compiled executable as admin

Comment: Does it work if you escape the space unicode? "SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\u0020Defender"

Comment: @Justin no it does not

Comment: 32bit app on x64 system ?

Comment: Maybe being the antivirus it's actually windows that says no, even to admins. Can you manually mess with it in regedit? On my machine at least that path just doesn't exist

Comment: Looks like you should be using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE not HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: @Justin is right - use RegEdit to check.

Comment: Here's the question you meant to ask: *"Why does RegOpenKeyExA fail to open a key path that doesn't exist but works flawlessly for a path that does?"*

Comment: @RbMm No i am compiling as a 64 bit app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegOpenKeyEx()` allows spaces just fine.  MANY Registry keys have spaces in their names.

Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which means the key you are trying to open does not exist.  And indeed, the `Windows Defender` key does not exist in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, it exists in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` instead.

[image]

---

BTW, `KEY_WRITE` includes `KEY_SET_VALUE` (among others), and `KEY_READ` includes `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` (among others), so technically you are opening the key with just `KEY_WRITE|KEY_READ`. Which is likely to fail unless your program is running with elevated permissions, since most of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is read-only to non-admin users.  It is rarely of good idea to open a key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for both read and write permissions at the same time.  If you need to read something, open the key for read-only access, which is likely to succeed.  If you need to write something, open the key for write-only access, which will succeed only if you have permission to write.